# Column Alias Too Long in sqlalchemy/Sybase ASE

Tags: sqlalchemy, sap-ase

I have sqlalchemy ORM mappings over a Sybase database. Some of my table names are fairly long, and I am getting the following error:

```
DBAPIError: (Error) ('HY000', "[HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver]
[SQL Server]The column heading that starts with 'RISK_AGGREGATION_GROUP_id_risk_agg' is 
too long. Maximum length is 30.
```

Is there any way I can either:

a) 'alias' the table inside sqlalchemy so that it uses shorter column aliases

b) increase the 30 character limit

I realise I can create view inside the database but would rather not touch it.

thanks

Comment: what version of sybase is this ?   docs say 255 is the max length for columns, tables, user defined identifiers: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug12.htm

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy usually sets the appropriate label length automatically, in the case of Sybase we never get any feedback on this dialect so we don't have a per-sybase default plugged in, but it is configurable via label_length:

```
engine = create_engine("sybase+pyodbc://...", label_length=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just can answer about the section b).
In sybase, you can't increase the character limit!

Regarding a) I don't know if that is possible but my sugestion is for you to change the table names!

Comment: yep, and if you change tables (add/remove columns) you might need to refresh those views